# Android MVVM/ViewModel for RecyclerView with infinite scrolling (load more) - How to handle data on configuration change

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel

So I have a `RecyclerView` with infinite scrolling. I first do a network call to my API and get a first page of 20 items.

In my `ViewModel` (code below), I have an observable that triggers the network call in my repository using the page number.

So, when the user scrolls to the bottom, the page number is incremented, and it triggers another network request.

Here's the code in my `ViewModel`:

```
private val scheduleObservable = Transformations.switchMap(scheduleParams) { params: Map<String, Any> ->
    ScheduleRepository.schedule(params["organizationId"] as String, params["page"] as Int)
}

// This is the method I call in my Fragment to fetch another page
fun fetchSchedule(organizationId: String, page: Int) {
  val params = mapOf(
      "organizationId" to organizationId,
      "page" to page
  )
  scheduleParams.value = params
}

fun scheduleObservable() : LiveData<Resource<Items>> {
    return scheduleObservable
}
```

In my fragment, I observe scheduleObservable, and when it emits data, I append them to my RecyclerView's adapter:

```
viewModel.scheduleObservable().observe(this, Observer {
    it?.data?.let {    
        if (!isAppending) {
            adapter.replaceData(it)
        } else {
            adapter.addData(it)
        }
    }
})
```

The problem with my current implementation is that, on configuration change, I rebind my observer, and the observable emits the last fetched data. In my case, it will emit the last fetched page only.

When coming back from a configuration change, I would want to have the full list of items fetched to this point so I can repopulate the adapter with these.

I'm wondering what's the best way to solve this. Should I have two observables? Should I create a list variable in my ViewModel to store all the items fetched and use that list for my adapter?

I checked android-architecture-components on GitHub, but it's usually overkill compared for my needs (no database, no paging library, etc) and I get lost since I am still trying to wrap my head around architecture components.

Comment: Can you post your activity code as well

Comment: Just added the code for my Fragment. Shorten up for sake of brievety, but the logic is really just that. 

I think what I'll end up doing is keep a list variable of all items in my ViewModel, and number of last page fetched. I'll feed my adapter with that list variable. When my observable is triggered, i'll check if the page has already been fetched and if not, i'll append to my list. This should fix my issue, though I am not sure if there's a better way I could do this.

Comment: have you found any other way to implement this?